# Django: Add class to a div depending on a variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like to declare in the template a variable that allows me to position an image inside a section on the left or the right. I just don't understand how can I do it on the variable side.

Here's my current code,
`main.html` :

```
{% with img_left=False %}
{% include 'section-service.html' %}
{% endwith %}
```

`section-service.html`:

```
<div class="sect_service-inside {% if img_left=True %} serv_img-left {% else %} serv_img-right {% endif %}">
<div id="here_img">...</div>
<div id="here_text">...</div>
</div>
```

but I get the error `Could not parse the remainder: '=True' from 'img_left=True'`

Note that I'll use this section multiple times in the main.html page, that's why I'd like to have the variable left-right.

EDIT:
`views.py`:

```
def page(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')
```

Comment: Please can you show your View.

Comment: @Lewis done, nothing really complicated

Comment: @BenjaminCarafa `{% if img_left == True %}` use `==` not `=` also note the spaces. The parser splits on spaces so if you miss spaces you will get an error. Also infact you can skip `== True` simply write `{% if img_left %}`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want [widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/)
As example for form:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% if <something> %}
            {% render_field field class="<first class>" %}
    {% elif <something other> %}
            {% render_field field class="<second class>" %}
    {% else %}
            {% render_field field class="<other class>"  %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```